# selective filtering so that select rows only if cell A or cell B contains a value

Tags: excel, if-statement, filter, excel-formula, filtering

I have a dataset that contains baseball record, I want to pick only one team to look at, so is there anyway I can apply filter on HomeTeam and VisitTeam so that if either HomeTeam or VisitTeam contains the team name, say PHI, the who row stays?

E.g: I have the data

```
HomeTeam VisitTeam
PHI      CLE
ATL      NYC
DET      PHI
```

I want the first row and third row.

Thank you!

Comment: Wouldn't an [Advanced Filter](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Video-Advanced-filter-details-BBD0CB0A-8F90-43DF-BF77-6AD3774DC420) be appropriate for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [Avanced Filter](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Video-Advanced-filter-details-BBD0CB0A-8F90-43DF-BF77-6AD3774DC420) command. This is not really about programming at all; just about how to use the features of Excel that are readily available and already well documented.

[image: Advanced_Filter_Baseball]

Comment: Thank you! I used advanced filter and macro on all my data. Really useful!